# Is "doctor put on some stitches" okay?

Tags: prepositions

What's the right verb in English for describing a doctor's action of putting stitches on the damaged area of patient's body?

Is the following sentence okay in English?

> I got a foot injury last night. Had to go to hospital and doctor **put
> on** four stitches.

I am afraid this one sounds wrong - as if doctor was putting on some stitches, that is, like he would be putting on some clothes.

Answer (score 3):

The doctor would “put **in**” some stitches **not** “on”.

Comment: Agreed. However, I think it would be more usual to say "I had to have four stitches", or "The wound needed four stitches".